# Binomial experiment with parameters $n = 10$ and $\theta = 1/3$, and denote $X$ to be the number of successes, then $P_\theta(X = 0) = 0.0282$, etc

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood

Chapter **2.1. Classical Definition** of the textbook *In All Likelihood -- Statistical Modelling and Inference Using Likelihood*, by Yudi Pawitan, says the following:

> Recall first the standard mode of deductive mathematical thinking: given a probabilistic model and parameter values we derive a description of data. In a deductive mode we derive the consequences of certain assumptions. For example, if we perform a binomial experiment with parameters $n = 10$ and $\theta = 1/3$, and denote $X$ to be the number of successes, then $P_\theta(X = 0) = 0.0282$, etc. This means if we repeat the experiment $10,000$ times, we expect around $282$ of them would yield no successes.

How was $P_\theta(X = 0) = 0.0282$ calculated? This is not clear to me.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: If you've correctly copied everything, it looks like an error. Perhaps the numbers got changed at some point but not all the changes got carried through.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica why is it an error? What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Actually, I've just googled for errata. See [here](http://fafner.meb.ki.se/personal/yudpaw/wp-content/uploads/likelihood/errors.htm) -- the $\frac{1}{3}$ should be $0.3$. That then gives the required $0.7^{10}=0.0282$ value.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Eh, where did $0.7^{10}$ come from? I don't understand  how this is the "number of successes" (yes, I did read the Wikipedia article).

Comment: 0 successes, 10 failures. $P(X=0) = {10 \choose 0}\, 0.3^0\, 0.7^{10} = 0.7^{10}$. Or you can just calculate the probability of 10 failures from first principles (simply assuming independence and invoking the product rule for probabiltiies)